# Script to loop over list of hashes in a file stuck with variable from the first iteration

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am currently attending a class on network security and we need to crack hashed passwords. To do so, we use hashcat. Since there are a lot of hashes, I am trying to write a script that would test the hashed password with all the hashes contained in the list. My script is as follows:

```
 1 #! /bin/bash
  2 listhsh="hashlist.txt"
  3 
  4 
  5 while read file; do
  6         echo $file
  7         hashcat -a 0 -m $file -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
  8 done < $listhsh
```

the file contains the following values. These are codes defining the type of hash to be tested.

```
900
0
5100
100
1300
1400
10800
1700
5000
600
```

The problem I have is that the script opens the file, takes the first line that contains the code for hash type to be tested and runs hashcat with the value in `$file=900`. However, once the test finishes with the first value, the script executes hashcat with the same value of `$file=900`. So the end result is hashcat doing the same test with `$file=900` as many times as there are values in the list.

Comment: https://hashcat.net/hashcat/

Comment: I can't recreate your problem with just `echo` in the loop – I suppose `echo` also prints only the first value for you?

Comment: Yes it does: echo print 900 once and never again

Comment: you will get better traction if you update your question with a better title

Comment: Hmmmm, I ran through your script again, and it should work fine.  I am not 100% sure why your's is not looping properly.   Maybe it is the space in the shebang line `#! /bin/bash` should be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @Terrance Spaces  after `#!` are allowed ever since Unix Version 8 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276751/85039

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Ah, I actually did not know that.  Thank you!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be a `for` loop.  The `-m` option is for the hashes to be ran.  The file is supposed to feed in value and loop each hash type.

The following changes should help your script. I substituted `hash` for `file`.

```
#!/bin/bash
listhsh="hashlist.txt"

for hash in $(cat $listhsh); do
echo $hash
    hashcat -a 0 -m $hash -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
done
```

As a test, I ran the line as an echo line to see if it would work:

```
~$ ./hashcat_test 
900
hashcat -a 0 -m 900 -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
0
hashcat -a 0 -m 0 -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
5100
hashcat -a 0 -m 5100 -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
100
hashcat -a 0 -m 100 -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
1300
hashcat -a 0 -m 1300 -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
1400
hashcat -a 0 -m 1400 -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
10800
hashcat -a 0 -m 10800 -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
1700
hashcat -a 0 -m 1700 -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
5000
hashcat -a 0 -m 5000 -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
600
hashcat -a 0 -m 600 -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: $file is defined on each run as what `read` receives from the < operator. It' a fairly common syntax:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/

Glad to see your version works though. I don't have hashcat available to test mine :P

Comment: By Jove, you're right. I missed a real obvious one there.

Comment: @Ketzak Well, the file is actually defined, but I think there is an issue with the while loop.  I changed mine to a for loop instead.

Comment: I really like your solution, and I'm gonna tuck that one away for later!

Comment: Note that this approach works only because there's no blank lines in the file as well as no multiple items per line. Proper way to read a file line by line is still via `while IFS= read -r line; do...done < input.txt` type of file.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Very well put!  I really have this bad habit of not thinking of stuff like that.  I have used it in my scripts before, but somehow I end up back in `for` loops, but normally that is because the info that is being fed into it usually does not contain blanks.  So, very good info my friend!  Many thanks!  :)

Comment: @Terrance Always welcome ! :) Just trying to warn new people to shell scripting who stumble upon this question not to make assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You're not quoting your expansions, so they're being evaluated by the shell, which could be problematic. Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash
listhsh="hashlist.txt"
while read file; do
    echo "$file"
    hashcat -a 0 -m "$file" -O ~/devoir_PIII_Alice.txt /usr/lib/rockyou.txt
done < $listhsh
```

These could be useful:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/